Why do the Schwarzschild and FLRW metrics treat curvature so differently
In the Schwarzschild metric, which describes a black hole, when a massive body crosses the event horizon, the radius and curvature of the black hole immediately increase. The increase in curvature is associated with a mass which is equal to, but not additional to, the mass of the body that crossed the event horizon. If the body heads for the singularity and is crushed out of existence, its mass remains as the mass of curvature. But at all times, there is only ever one mass.
In the FLRW metric on the other hand, the mass of curvature is independent, and additional to, the mass of matter. Why is there this difference? Why is no curvature associated with the mass of matter?

What do you mean by "mass of curvature"? Mass is not well defined in GR in general.

@anders sandberg.


As I understand it, if a massive body reaches the singularity at the centre of a black hole it is 'crushed' out of existence, but its mass or energy remains as the mass or energy of the increased curvature of the black hole.


In FLRW curvature has an energy density (with a mass density equivalent).



@JohnHobson That's a bit of a strange description of what happens. In reality no external observer can ever see any object pass the event horizon, and inside the event horizon (if you were to magically get there) there would be three time dimensions and one spatial dimension (if you believe the Schwarzschild metric's math).

@controlgroup. I struggle a bit with this. Objects do merge with black holes. We can measure their gravity waves. And black holes do get bigger, or how do they form in the first place?

For one, objects approach the event horizon for an infinite period of time (barring black hole decay), but they can't cross it. Try integrating external-coordinates motion into a black hole accounting for gravitational time dilation, which makes apparent velocity go to zero at the event horizon. At that point they're effectively part of the black hole. As to how they form in the first place... a detailed physical process has yet to be described mathematically.

Remember that the Schwartzschild solution doesn't describe a real black hole though, it describes an eternal static spherically symmetric solution to Einstein's field equations.

Interesting comments but do they really mean there is no answer to the question?

The Schwarzschild and FLRW metrics treat curvature in exactly the same way; they are both solutions to the Einstein field equations. It sounds like you've been misled by some pop science descriptions of these metrics (not surprising, there are some poor popsci descriptions of relativity out there).
The FLRW metric describes a spacetime in which space is uniformly filled with matter which has no associated stress or pressure -- a featureless, motionless dust. The curvature of spacetime arises from this dust. It is a reasonable approximation to the universe on a large scale.
The Schwarzscild metric, by contrast, is a vacuum solution, with no matter at all. This may surprise you. The metric does have a parameter $M$ which is usually interpreted as the "mass" of the black hole, but that mass isn't present in the spacetime. If it's anywhere it's "in" the singularity, which isn't part of spacetime. The Scwarzscild metric is a reasonable approximation to some real world scenarios, where only the mass of the black hole is significant and the mass of infalling matter is negligible. If you actually care about the mass of the infalling objects then you'll have to include them from the start. This is much more complicated, which is why popular accounts tend to gloss over it, but real physicists working on problems like black hole mergers do not use the Schwarzscild metric at all but rather use numerical methods to solve the Einstein field equations

@EricsmithThank you for this - but it does raise a subsidiary. From your 2nd paragraph it sounds as though if there is matter in the form of dust, then spacetime should be curved. But I thought in the standard model, spacetime was flat.
and a second subsidiary. So presumably, when matter approaches a black hole, it perturbs the Schwarzschild metric such that there is no longer infinite time dilation at the event horizon?

As I mentioned, the Schwarzschild metric is an idealized situation with no matter present. To take into account the effects of matter you have to do some pretty complicated calculations,  which I haven't done myself, but my understanding is that basically the event horizon expands to encompass the new matter, and this takes place in a finite amount of time relative to a distant observer.

Is there a relationship between the density of matter outside the black hole and the rate of expansion? I have speculated that if the density outside is the same as that of the black hole, the expansion rate will be the speed of light. And noted that the correct metric would then be FLRW with curvature density set to 100%, which describes a black hole expanding at the speed of light.
